# Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid

Tags: c, linux, visual-studio-code, arch

I keep getting the `Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid` error in vs-code when trying to run my hello world c program.

I was suggested to run `sudo pacman -S gdp` however that returns an error: `error: target not found: gdp`

my launch.json:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": []
}
```

Comment: It is probably `gdb` not gdp.

Comment: @LarsFischer Thank you! I cant believe i didn't notice that. IG i should start wearing my glasses.

Answer (score 0):

`gdb` was not installed and the error was because of a missread

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).